# How to exit a running process and run the next commands in the shell script

Tags: linux, bash, automation

I am trying to automate the installation of packages on a server through a script given below.

```
#/bin/bash
cd kms-omni-build/
./bin/kms-build-run.sh
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x -o nodesource_setup.sh
sudo bash nodesource_setup.sh
sudo apt install nodejs -y
```

The problem is that ./bin/kms-build-run.sh script does not exit automatically and does not give the prompt back. Due to this the next commands do not get executed. This does not let nodejs to be installed automatically.

Is there a way to get the prompt back automatically from such a shell script.

Comment: I suggest to fix `./bin/kms-build-run.sh`.

Comment: Do you want to end `./bin/kms-build-run.sh` after a given time?

Comment: What's the contents of `./bin/kms-build-run.sh`?

Comment: @nooblag https://github.com/Kurento/kms-omni-build/blob/master/bin/kms-build-run.sh

Comment: If you just want it to build KMS and not run it, try using `kms-build-run.sh --build-only`

Comment: Please add details on what resources you have consulted for coming to StackOverflow for assistance. https://ecdn.teacherspayteachers.com/thumbitem/Try-3-Before-Me-Freebie--3355063-1503661824/original-3355063-1.jpg

Comment: @dmcgill50 looked for an answer on google and youtube and consulted my colleagues.

Comment: running the shell script in the background has worked
    ./bin/kms-build-run.sh &,
& helps to run script in background.